# Removing a key from a Perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash in which its keys are hashes. I want to rename some of the keys inside the primary hash by adding a key with the desired name and deleting the unwanted key. I succeeded in adding a key, but I'm unable to delete the original key.

This statement isn't working

```
delete $primary_hash{$sec_hash_key};
```

If I print the value of `$primary_hash{$sec_hash_key}` it's returning `$HASH(0X*)`. I don't know what is missing in syntax?

Comment: are you sure `$sec_hash_key` is a string?

Comment: Can you print your data structure using `Data::Dumper`?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper;` `print Dumper \%primary_hash;`

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, hash keys are ***always*** strings. If you specify a non-string object as a hash key, perl will stringify it to be able to use it as a key. Therefore, when you say:

> I have hash in which it's [sic] keys are hashes

you are wrong. They are not hashes, they are strings.

Now, if you did something like:

```
my %h = (a => 1);
my %g = (%h => 2);
```

That would have created `%g` as:

```
(a => 1, 2 => undef);
```

If, instead, you did `%g = (\%h => 2)`, that would have created something along the lines of:

```
 %g = (
      'HASH(0x7ff92882cbd8)' => 2
 );
```

Note that the key is a string. You cannot go back to the data structure from that string.

Answer (score -3):

What do you mean by 'delete'? Free the memory, or just want the
key to be undefined, when checking for it in an `if` statement?

The latter you can achieve my setting the key `undef`.

`$primary_hash{$sec_hash_key} = undef;`.

But please provide a full working example of your problem, so
it can be reproduced.